# Google ranking - difference between example.com and example.com/?ref=id

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url

Does it impact a site's Google ranking if I link to the site with a "referrer" query-string? e.g: `example.com/?ref=mysite` instead of `example.com` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as that url redirects to the main url (and wipes the referrer parameters itself, which you can check by just following the link) or that parameter is set in [google webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to be ignored by googlebot (which is only easy to find out if you're the owner of the site, really), it should make essentially no difference.

Otherwise you could resort to [using the](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394) `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/">` (again if you are the owner of the site being linked to).

Answer (score 2):

The question mark is normally a signal for dynamic content, which may send signals to the robot ... some dynamic sites loop into infinity with different urls all with the same content.

Inherently  example.com/?ref=mysite  example.com/?ref=mysite&anothertag=something example.com/?ref=mysite&anothertag=Duplicatecontent More than likely will all pull up the same content while example.com/mysite would signal static content and example.com/mysite/anothertag would be different content.

Currently many CMS systems use ? marks and they are indexed by google. None the less, they are by nature not search engine friendly. Duplicate content is a problem for robots as well as url loops that trap search engine spiders.

I would strongly discourage using ? but I can not they will specifically harm a sites ranking. Ultimately the URL with the ? will be given importance by links going to it from the site and other sites in the same way that none ? URL are given importance. The ? mark itself does not create a penalty, rather opens a can of worms regarding duplicate content and duplicate content is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it impacts site page ranking. ? mark denotes dynamic content.
The best way to so it would be to use links seperated by -
like:

google-ranking-difference-between-example-com-and-example-com-ref-id

which are used by major CMS and blog sites which are proving very useful.